# Issue with plotting daily data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to plot daily data from 9 variables in ggplot, but the graph I get cannot handle the date variable properly. The x axis is unreadable and its impossible to read the plot. I'm guessing there's an issue with the handling of dates.

Here's the data: 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/su.csv

Here's the code I've been using:

```
su=read.csv(file="su.csv", head=TRUE)

meltdf=melt(su)

ggplot(meltdf, aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable))+geom_line()
```

and here's the output:

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/output.jpg
```

here's the same plot done in excel, why does it look completely different?

Comment: Please define `not properly`, right now it is now obvious what your problem is. In addition, your pdf is very large, please save it in an image format like `png`.

Answer (score 1):

Right now `Date` is a factor, not a real R date object. You can use `strptime` to parse your string into a `POSIXct` object. This will yield much better results.

---

Not directly related to your question, but in addition you could use `facet_wrap` to split up the timeseries and stack them on top of each other. I wrote a small function to calculate the indices needed for `facet_wrap`:

```
createTimeseriesCutupIdx = function(ncuts, nrows, labels) {
  if(missing(labels)) labels = LETTERS[1:ncuts]
  pointsPerCutup = floor((1/ncuts) * nrows)
  idx = rep(labels, each = pointsPerCutup)
  if(length(idx) < nrows) {
    idx[(length(idx) + 1):nrows] <- idx[length(idx)]
  }   
  return(idx)
}
```

and example of how to use it:

```
require(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
tserie_length = 5000
df = data.frame(t = as.POSIXct("2006-01-01") + (1:tserie_length) * 3600, 
                value = runif(tserie_length))
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = value)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

```
df$idx = createTimeseriesCutupIdx(ncuts = 5, nrows = nrow(df))
ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = value)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   facet_wrap(~ idx, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1)
```

[image]

This makes it possible to plot much larger timeseries in a meaningful way.

Comment: here's a plot done in excel, why does it look completely different? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/su.tiff

Comment: Probably because the data I use above is not your data, but a random dataset I generated in the answer.

Comment: this is the error I get: > su$Date=strptime(su$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Date", value = list(sec = numeric(0),  : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 4787

Comment: Your format argument is not good, resulting in NA's. Read the documentation of strptime carefully and construct the correct format. For example, you list `%Y` (year in four digits) as your first format entry. However, this is the last entry.